# How to get DataType specific DataTable from XML

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, type-conversion

How to get DataType specific DataTable from XML

This is my code

```
string XMLReportFormat =@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Table>
    <ReportBody>
      <TableRow>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Key>First1</Key>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Key>FirstChild4</Key>
      </TableRow>
    </ReportBody>
</Table>";

StringReader sReader = new StringReader(XMLReportFormat);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

if (sReader == null)
    return null;
ds.ReadXml(sReader);
```

Here I am getting all `DataType` of columns as `String`.
I want some columns like `ID` and `ParentID` as `Integer`

Comment: You are setting this xml values into a property or something?

Comment: @Vinicius : why property comes to scene ? ... I am not using any properties

Comment: Because if your are using properties you can try to parse the value of xml attribute(ex : ID) to the type of a property that have the same name, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ! I found the answer.

```
private static DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableRow");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ParentID", typeof(int)));
    return dt;
}
public static DataTable GetReportFormatFromXML(string XMLReportFormat)
{
    if (XMLReportFormat == string.Empty)
        return null;
    StringReader sReader = new StringReader(XMLReportFormat);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    if (sReader == null)
        return null;
    ds.Tables.Add(CreateDataTable());
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

This line helps me :)

```
ds.Tables.Add(CreateDataTable());
```

Comment: The sReader seems to be not used anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I have found is make sure your DataSet reads an xml schema. The schema will set the data types of the XML for your DataSet.

```
DataSet.ReadXmlSchema
```

i.e.:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(Server.MapPath("/YourSchema.xsd"));
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("/YourXML.xml"));
```

I was having an issue using Dynamic data in Microsoft Reports because everything coming from the XML was a string. I tried copying items to a new DataSet with dataTypes defined but this was much easier. You can have c# write a default schema for any xml file that you can then edit as needed.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("Data.xml");
ds.WriteXmlSchema("Data.xsd");
```

I know this post is old but it helped me out so I thought I would share what I learned.

Answer (score 0):

sorry try this TryParse

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

```
  DataRow dr = ...;
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(dr["column"], out number);
  if (result)
  {
     // is a number , you can use it        
  }
  else
  {
     // convert your data to String
  }
```