# How to create DataTable from xml file with types in c#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, xsd, dataset

I have this code that create a xml file from DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "sdf";
dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(1,2);
dt.Rows.Add(3,4);
dt.WriteXml(@"d:\test123.xml");
```

In another program I need to read the xml file and to create DataTable/DataSet **with integer columns**.

```
dt.ReadXml(@"d:\test123.xml");
```

This code generate a DataTable with string columns.

How can I define the types of the columns in the DataTable?

Comment: Duplicated question [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685492/how-to-get-datatype-specific-datatable-from-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the columns before read xml:

```
var dt = new DataTable {TableName = "sdf"};
dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(int));
dt.ReadXml(@"d:\test123.xml");
```

Comment: DataTable does not support Schema XSD